# How to show New products from specific category in Magento?

Tags: magento

How can i show new products from a specific category in magento and just show its image,Name , and description? And is it possible to add it on the newsletter?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code below. Set your `news_from_date` and `news_to_date` dates and the `CategoryId`

It've created it just now and tested it with a prepared product:

```
$collection =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()  
                ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3))
                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'sku', 'description', 'small_image', 'news_from_date', 'news_to_date', 'category_id'))               
                ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date',array('date' => true, 'gteq' => '2013-05-03'))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('date' => true, 'lteq' => '2013-11-25') )
                ;

foreach ($collection as $product) 
{

    var_dump( $product->getName() );
    var_dump( $product->getDescription() );
    var_dump( $product->getNewsFromDate() );
    var_dump( $product->getNewsToDate() );

}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply, Where would i put this code and how would i use this code

Comment: It's php code, so you can add it as a single `.phtml` file in magento `app/design/frontend/...` context. If you to use it as newsletter content, maybe you have to create a `block` for that to embed the output of the script in the newsletter cms editor ... but I don't know, how to do this exactly ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$categoryid = 12;

$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($categoryid);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($collection as $_product) { ?>

<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200); ?>" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></a>
enter code here
```